# toDataURL() in Angular2 returns URL with blank image

Tags: angular, typescript, todataurl

To be in context: I'm using latest version of Angular with TypeScript and I need to show the selected image from a file selector. After select any image i convert to base64 to get the String. Given that String i show the selected image, and after i'll push to a REST server as an attribute of an entity.

The problem is that I not getting the right base64 String of the image, but i can see in Google developer tools that there's two URL of the image generated: one is the correct, and the other is blank, the last is which one is returning toDataURL() function.

I been trying with lots of examples and different codes but still not working.

Also i have to say that it works randomly about 1% of the times i tested.

Following the code:

**floor-form.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="showForm" class="form-group row">
  <input type="file" id="picture" autofocus=""  #file (change)="addPicture(file)" />
    <img [src]="floor.picture" />
</div>
```

**floor-form.component.ts**

```
addPicture(input) {
   const file = input.files[0];
   const reader = new FileReader();

   reader.addEventListener('load', (event: any) => {
      this.floor.picture = this.resizeImage(event.target.result, file.type, 480, 480);
   }, false);

   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}


resizeImage(imageData, type, MAX_WIDTH = 480, MAX_HEIGHT = 480) {
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = imageData;
    let width = img.width;
    let height = img.height;
    if (width > height) {
      if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
        height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
        width = MAX_WIDTH;
      }
    } else {
      if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
        width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
        height = MAX_HEIGHT;
      }
    }
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
    return canvas.toDataURL(type);
  }
```

[chrome developer tools screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21TRb.png) In this screenshot can see it returns empty URL, but if i delete the `if's` of the `resizeImage()` i'll get full URL's but with empty image.

Sorry if I missing something but I'm new on Angular.